# Spring Batch loop reader while changing sql query and write in different files

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-batch

first of all thank you very much for taking the trouble to read this consultation. I embarked on the use of Spring Batch for the realization of a project, my query is as follows. I have a reader, which according to the value of a variable completes the fields of a query and brings me the results and proceeds to write them in a file. The problem is that one of the possible variables is "ALL" which should run the reader three times changing the query fields for CUSTOMER, ACCOUNT and PRODUCT. This would give me different results, as they are different queries, and should be written to different files.

Is there any way I can do this? From what I can research, I cannot modify a Job while it is running, so I cannot add another Step to it according to the value "ALL".

Thank you very much for your time.

**Resource**

```
public Resource outputResource() {
        String outputDir = env.getProperty("uy.com.antel.up.data.folder.out");
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat hourdateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String outputName = outputDir + "webUserbatch-" + hourdateFormat.format(date) + ".txt";
        File file = new File(outputName);
        if(file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(file);

        return resource;
    }
```

**Reader**

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader reader(DataSource dataSource, @Value("#{jobParameters}") Map<String, Object> map) {
        JdbcCursorItemReader reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader();
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setRowMapper(new UsuariosProductosRowMapper());
        String urn = "", fechaInicio = "", fechaFin = "", ultimafecha = "", tabla_consultar = "";
        if (map.get("urn") != null) {
            urn = map.get("urn").toString();
        }
        if (map.get("fechaInicio") != null) {
            fechaInicio = map.get("fechaInicio").toString();
        }
        if (map.get("fechaFin") != null) {
            fechaFin = map.get("fechaFin").toString();
        }
        if (map.get("ultimafecha") != null) {
            ultimafecha = map.get("ultimafecha").toString();
        }
        if (map.get("tabla_consultar") != null) {
            tabla_consultar = map.get("tabla_consultar").toString();
        }
        String tipoGeneracion = env.getProperty("uy.com.antel.up.tipo.carga");

        Date date = new Date();

        //Se le asigna el valor de "" para que se pueda realizar busquedas personalizadas, sino se maneja solamente con la carga inicial 
        //tipoGeneracion = "";

        LOG.info("URN: " + urn);
        LOG.info("Fecha desde: " + fechaInicio);
        LOG.info("Fecha hasta: " + fechaFin);
        LOG.info("Ultima fecha: " + ultimafecha);
        LOG.info("Tabla consultar: " + tabla_consultar);


        //eliminar esto para que tome otro valor por afuera del inicial
        //tabla accreditation_event
        //datos faltantes: user_name, acrreditation_level

        String table_online_id = "";
        String table_reference = "";
        String shorcut_table_online = "";
        String shorcut_table_reference = "";
        String attribute_table_online ="";

        if (tabla_consultar == null || tabla_consultar.equals(CommandArgument.ALL.name()) ) {
            //
            //At this point the program should run the query for CUSTOMER, ACCOUNT and PRODUCT
            //
        }else{
            if (tabla_consultar.equals(CommandArgument.CUSTOMER.name())) {
                table_online_id = "online_id_customer";
                table_reference = "customer_reference";
                shorcut_table_online = "oidc";
                attribute_table_online = "customer";
                shorcut_table_reference = "cr";
            }else if (tabla_consultar.equals(CommandArgument.PRODUCT.name())) {
                table_online_id = "online_id_product";
                table_reference = "product_reference";
                shorcut_table_online = "oidp";
                attribute_table_online = "product";
                shorcut_table_reference = "pr";
            }else {
                table_online_id = "online_id_account";
                table_reference = "account_reference";
                shorcut_table_online = "oida";
                attribute_table_online = "account";
                shorcut_table_reference = "ar";
            }
          }





        if (tipoGeneracion.equalsIgnoreCase("inicial")) {
            reader.setSql("select ul.user_name  as \"userName\"," + shorcut_table_reference +".urn as \"urn\", ace.wbu_action as \"action\", al.name as \"accreditation_level\", ace.date as \"fecha\"\r\n" 
                    + " from " + table_online_id +" "+ shorcut_table_online +", online_entity_association oea, accreditation_event ace, " + table_reference + " " +  shorcut_table_reference +", user_login ul, acreditation_level al \r\n"
                    + " where " + shorcut_table_online+".id=oea.id and \r\n" + " oea.acreditacion=ace.id and \r\n"
                    + " "+shorcut_table_online+"."+attribute_table_online+"=" + shorcut_table_reference +".id and \r\n" + " ul.online_identity="+shorcut_table_online+".online_identity and \r\n" + " ace.level=al.id and \r\n"
                    + " oea.valid=true and " + "ace.date<='" + date + "'");
        } else if (urn.isEmpty() && fechaInicio.isEmpty() && fechaFin.isEmpty()) {

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
            cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);

            Date firstDateOfPreviousMonth = cal.getTime();
            String fechaDesde = sdf.format(firstDateOfPreviousMonth);

            cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE)); 

            Date lastDateOfPreviousMonth = cal.getTime();

            String fechaHasta = sdf.format(lastDateOfPreviousMonth);

            reader.setSql("select ul.user_name  as \"userName\"," + shorcut_table_reference +".urn as \"urn\", ace.wbu_action as \"action\", al.name as \"accreditation_level\", ace.date as \"fecha\"\r\n" 
                    + " from " + table_online_id +" "+ shorcut_table_online +", online_entity_association oea, accreditation_event ace, " + table_reference + " " +  shorcut_table_reference +", user_login ul, acreditation_level al \r\n"
                    + " where " + shorcut_table_online+".id=oea.id and \r\n" + " oea.acreditacion=ace.id and \r\n"
                    + " "+shorcut_table_online+"."+attribute_table_online+"=" + shorcut_table_reference +".id and \r\n" + " ul.online_identity="+shorcut_table_online+".online_identity and \r\n" + " ace.level=al.id and \r\n"
                    + " oea.valid=true and ace.date>='" + fechaDesde + "' and ace.date<='" + fechaHasta + "'");
        } else if (!urn.isEmpty() && !fechaInicio.isEmpty() && !fechaFin.isEmpty()) {
            reader.setSql("select ul.user_name  as \"userName\"," + shorcut_table_reference +".urn as \"urn\", ace.wbu_action as \"action\", al.name as \"accreditation_level\", ace.date as \"fecha\"\r\n" 
                    + " from " + table_online_id +" "+ shorcut_table_online +", online_entity_association oea, accreditation_event ace, " + table_reference + " " +  shorcut_table_reference +", user_login ul, acreditation_level al \r\n"
                    + " where " + shorcut_table_online+".id=oea.id and \r\n" + " oea.acreditacion=ace.id and \r\n"
                    + " "+shorcut_table_online+"."+attribute_table_online+"=" + shorcut_table_reference +".id and \r\n" + " ul.online_identity="+shorcut_table_online+".online_identity and \r\n" + " ace.level=al.id and \r\n"
                    + " oea.valid=true and " + "      ace.date>='" + map.get("fechaInicio") + "' and \r\n"
                    + "   ace.date<='" + map.get("fechaFin") + "' and  pr.urn like '%" + map.get("urn") + "%'");
        } else if (!urn.isEmpty() && fechaInicio.isEmpty() && fechaFin.isEmpty()) {
            reader.setSql("select ul.user_name  as \"userName\"," + shorcut_table_reference +".urn as \"urn\", ace.wbu_action as \"action\", al.name as \"accreditation_level\", ace.date as \"fecha\"\r\n" 
                    + " from " + table_online_id +" "+ shorcut_table_online +", online_entity_association oea, accreditation_event ace, " + table_reference + " " +  shorcut_table_reference +", user_login ul, acreditation_level al \r\n"
                    + " where " + shorcut_table_online+".id=oea.id and \r\n" + " oea.acreditacion=ace.id and \r\n"
                    + " "+shorcut_table_online+"."+attribute_table_online+"=" + shorcut_table_reference +".id and \r\n" + " ul.online_identity="+shorcut_table_online+".online_identity and \r\n" + " ace.level=al.id and \r\n"
                    + " oea.valid=true and " + " pr.urn like '%" + map.get("urn") + "%'");
        } else if (urn.isEmpty() && !fechaInicio.isEmpty() && !fechaFin.isEmpty()) {
            reader.setSql("select ul.user_name  as \"userName\"," + shorcut_table_reference +".urn as \"urn\", ace.wbu_action as \"action\", al.name as \"accreditation_level\", ace.date as \"fecha\"\r\n" 
                    + " from " + table_online_id +" "+ shorcut_table_online +", online_entity_association oea, accreditation_event ace, " + table_reference + " " +  shorcut_table_reference +", user_login ul, acreditation_level al \r\n"
                    + " where " + shorcut_table_online+".id=oea.id and \r\n" + " oea.acreditacion=ace.id and \r\n"
                    + " "+shorcut_table_online+"."+attribute_table_online+"=" + shorcut_table_reference +".id and \r\n" + " ul.online_identity="+shorcut_table_online+".online_identity and \r\n" + " ace.level=al.id and \r\n"
                    + " oea.valid=true and " + "      ace.date>='" + map.get("fechaInicio") + "' and \r\n"
                    + "   ace.date<='" + map.get("fechaFin") + "'");
        } else if (urn.isEmpty() && !fechaInicio.isEmpty() && fechaFin.isEmpty()) {
            reader.setSql("select ul.user_name  as \"userName\"," + shorcut_table_reference +".urn as \"urn\", ace.wbu_action as \"action\", al.name as \"accreditation_level\", ace.date as \"fecha\"\r\n" 
                    + " from " + table_online_id +" "+ shorcut_table_online +", online_entity_association oea, accreditation_event ace, " + table_reference + " " +  shorcut_table_reference +", user_login ul, acreditation_level al \r\n"
                    + " where " + shorcut_table_online+".id=oea.id and \r\n" + " oea.acreditacion=ace.id and \r\n"
                    + " "+shorcut_table_online+"."+attribute_table_online+"=" + shorcut_table_reference +".id and \r\n" + " ul.online_identity="+shorcut_table_online+".online_identity and \r\n" + " ace.level=al.id and \r\n"
                    + " oea.valid=true and " + "      ace.date>='" + map.get("fechaInicio") + "'");
        } else if (!urn.isEmpty() && !fechaInicio.isEmpty() && fechaFin.isEmpty()) {
            reader.setSql("select ul.user_name  as \"userName\"," + shorcut_table_reference +".urn as \"urn\", ace.wbu_action as \"action\", al.name as \"accreditation_level\", ace.date as \"fecha\"\r\n" 
                    + " from " + table_online_id +" "+ shorcut_table_online +", online_entity_association oea, accreditation_event ace, " + table_reference + " " +  shorcut_table_reference +", user_login ul, acreditation_level al \r\n"
                    + " where " + shorcut_table_online+".id=oea.id and \r\n" + " oea.acreditacion=ace.id and \r\n"
                    + " "+shorcut_table_online+"."+attribute_table_online+"=" + shorcut_table_reference +".id and \r\n" + " ul.online_identity="+shorcut_table_online+".online_identity and \r\n" + " ace.level=al.id and \r\n"
                    + " oea.valid=true and " + "      ace.date>='" + map.get("fechaInicio") + "' and \r\n"
                    + " pr.urn like '%" + map.get("urn") + "%'");
        } else if (!urn.isEmpty() && fechaInicio.isEmpty() && !fechaFin.isEmpty()) {
            reader.setSql("select ul.user_name  as \"userName\"," + shorcut_table_reference +".urn as \"urn\", ace.wbu_action as \"action\", al.name as \"accreditation_level\", ace.date as \"fecha\"\r\n" 
                    + " from " + table_online_id +" "+ shorcut_table_online +", online_entity_association oea, accreditation_event ace, " + table_reference + " " +  shorcut_table_reference +", user_login ul, acreditation_level al \r\n"
                    + " where " + shorcut_table_online+".id=oea.id and \r\n" + " oea.acreditacion=ace.id and \r\n"
                    + " "+shorcut_table_online+"."+attribute_table_online+"=" + shorcut_table_reference +".id and \r\n" + " ul.online_identity="+shorcut_table_online+".online_identity and \r\n" + " ace.level=al.id and \r\n"
                    + " oea.valid=true and " + "      ace.date<='" + map.get("fechaFin") + "' and  pr.urn like '%"
                    + map.get("urn") + "%'");
        } else if (urn.isEmpty() && fechaInicio.isEmpty() && !fechaFin.isEmpty()) {
            reader.setSql("select ul.user_name  as \"userName\"," + shorcut_table_reference +".urn as \"urn\", ace.wbu_action as \"action\", al.name as \"accreditation_level\", ace.date as \"fecha\"\r\n" 
                    + " from " + table_online_id +" "+ shorcut_table_online +", online_entity_association oea, accreditation_event ace, " + table_reference + " " +  shorcut_table_reference +", user_login ul, acreditation_level al \r\n"
                    + " where " + shorcut_table_online+".id=oea.id and \r\n" + " oea.acreditacion=ace.id and \r\n"
                    + " "+shorcut_table_online+"."+attribute_table_online+"=" + shorcut_table_reference +".id and \r\n" + " ul.online_identity="+shorcut_table_online+".online_identity and \r\n" + " ace.level=al.id and \r\n"
                    + " oea.valid=true and " + "      ace.date<='" + map.get("fechaFin") + "'");
        } else if (urn.isEmpty() && fechaInicio.isEmpty() && fechaFin.isEmpty() && !ultimafecha.isEmpty()) {
            reader.setSql("select ul.user_name  as \"userName\"," + shorcut_table_reference +".urn as \"urn\", ace.wbu_action as \"action\", al.name as \"accreditation_level\", ace.date as \"fecha\"\r\n" 
                    + " from " + table_online_id +" "+ shorcut_table_online +", online_entity_association oea, accreditation_event ace, " + table_reference + " " +  shorcut_table_reference +", user_login ul, acreditation_level al \r\n"
                    + " where " + shorcut_table_online+".id=oea.id and \r\n" + " oea.acreditacion=ace.id and \r\n"
                    + " "+shorcut_table_online+"."+attribute_table_online+"=" + shorcut_table_reference +".id and \r\n" + " ul.online_identity="+shorcut_table_online+".online_identity and \r\n" + " ace.level=al.id and \r\n"
                    + " oea.valid=true and " + "      ace.date='" + map.get("ultimafecha") + "'");
        }

        LOG.info("SQL: " + reader.getSql());

        int counter = 0;
        ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
        reader.open(executionContext);
        Object customerCredit = new Object();
        while (customerCredit != null) {
            try {
                customerCredit = reader.read();
                counter++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        LOG.info("Registros procesados: " + (counter - 1));

        reader.close();

        return reader;
    }
```

**Writer**

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<UsuariosProductos> writer() throws Exception {
        FlatFileItemWriter<UsuariosProductos> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        try {
            writer.setResource(this.outputResource());
            writer.open(new ExecutionContext());

            BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<UsuariosProductos> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
            fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] { "username", "urn", "fecha", "action", "accreditation_level"});

            DelimitedLineAggregator<UsuariosProductos> delLineAgg = new DelimitedLineAggregator<UsuariosProductos>();
            delLineAgg.setDelimiter(",");
            delLineAgg.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
            writer.setLineAggregator(delLineAgg);

            //agregar header
            writer.setHeaderCallback(new FlatFileHeaderCallback() {
                @Override
                public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
                    writer.write("------USERNAME------,--------URN--------,------------------FECHA------------------,--------ACTION--------,-------------------------ACCREDITATION_LEVEL-----");
                    writer.write("----------------------------------------");
                }
            });

            //eliminar footer
            writer.setFooterCallback(new FlatFileFooterCallback() {
                @Override
                public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException {
//                  writer.write("Archivos procesados: ");
                    writer.write("----------------------------------------\r\n" + 
                            "----- FIN ARCHIVO DE PROCESADOS OK -----");
                }
            });

            writer.close();
        } catch (WriterNotOpenException e) {
            LOG.info("Excepcion encontrada: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return writer;

    }
```

**Job**

```
@Bean
    public Job usuariosProductosJob(JobListener listener, Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("usuariosProductosJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener)
                .flow(step1).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<UsuariosProductos> reader,
            ItemWriter<UsuariosProductos> writer, ItemProcessor<UsuariosProductos, UsuariosProductos> processor) {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<UsuariosProductos, UsuariosProductos>chunk(obtenerChunk())
                .reader(reader).processor(processor).writer(writer).build();
    }


    public Integer obtenerChunk() {
        Integer chunk = Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("uy.com.antel.up.chunk.step"));

        return chunk;
    }
```

**UsuariosProductRowMapper.class**

```
public class UsuariosProductosRowMapper implements RowMapper<UsuariosProductos>{

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsuariosProductosRowMapper.class);

    private static final String USERNAME = "userName";
    private static final String URN = "urn";
    private static final String FECHA = "fecha";
    private static final String ACTION = "action";
    private static final String ACCREDITATION_LEVEL = "accreditation_level";


    @Override
    public UsuariosProductos mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        UsuariosProductos up = new UsuariosProductos();
        up.setUsername(rs.getString(USERNAME));
        up.setUrn(rs.getString(URN));
        up.setAction(rs.getString(ACTION));
        up.setAccreditation_level(rs.getString(ACCREDITATION_LEVEL));

        LOG.info("Estoy en UsuariosProductosRow");

        LOG.info("resultSet: " + rs.toString());
        LOG.info("action: " + rs.getString(ACTION));
        LOG.info("accreditation_level: " + rs.getString(ACCREDITATION_LEVEL));

        try {
            java.sql.Timestamp fecha = rs.getTimestamp(FECHA);
            LOG.info("Fecha java sql: " + fecha);
            up.setFecha(fecha.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(rs.isLast()) {
            up.setProcesados(rs.getRow());
        }
        return up;
    }

}
```

**Proccesor**

```
public class UsuariosProductosProcessor implements ItemProcessor<UsuariosProductos, UsuariosProductos>{

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsuariosProductosProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public UsuariosProductos process(UsuariosProductos item) throws Exception {
        UsuariosProductos up = new UsuariosProductos();
        if(item.getUsername() != null)
            up.setUsername("userName: " + item.getUsername() + " ");
        else
            up.setUsername("userName: Not found ");
        // no igual, nada. null

        up.setUrn("urn: " + item.getUrn() + " ");
        up.setFecha("fechaAcreditación: " + item.getFecha() + " ");
        up.setAction("action: " + item.getAction() + " ");
        up.setAccreditation_level("accreditation_level: " + item.getAccreditation_level() + " ");

        return up;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looking at your reader definition with 15+ if statement in it, I really encourage you to break things down to smaller pieces. I don't know how do you test this, but I would make each job do one thing (and do it well) instead of a single job trying to cover all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the commentary of Mahmoud Ben Hassine I decided to use several jobs that do different tasks, but without breaking the structure that already existed in the code, since the software I'm working on belongs to a client, and I don't know how much I can modify from it.

What I did was the following, define a variable that takes the argument that is entered in the jar, and seeks to perform the procedure of the job associated with it. In the case of ALL, it will perform each job one after the other.

```
if (map.get("tabla_consultar") != null) {
            type_job = map.get("tabla_consultar").toString();
            if (type_job.equalsIgnoreCase(CommandArgument.ALL.name())) {
                map.put("tabla_consultar", new JobParameter(CommandArgument.ACCOUNT.name())); 
                executeJob(ctx.getBean("usuariosAccountJob", Job.class), jobLauncher, map);
                map.put("tabla_consultar", new JobParameter(CommandArgument.CUSTOMER.name()));
                executeJob(ctx.getBean("usuariosCustomerJob", Job.class), jobLauncher, map);
                map.put("tabla_consultar", new JobParameter(CommandArgument.PRODUCT.name()));
                executeJob(ctx.getBean("usuariosProductosJob", Job.class), jobLauncher, map);
            }else if (type_job.equalsIgnoreCase(CommandArgument.CUSTOMER.name())) {
                executeJob(ctx.getBean("usuariosCustomerJob", Job.class), jobLauncher, map);
            }else if (type_job.equalsIgnoreCase(CommandArgument.ACCOUNT.name())) {
                executeJob(ctx.getBean("usuariosAccountJob", Job.class), jobLauncher, map);
            }else {
                executeJob(ctx.getBean("usuariosProductosJob", Job.class), jobLauncher, map);
            }
        }
```

In the BatchConfiguration, I have a variable that checks which is the type of job you want to do, and from that it completes the fields of the query referring to the table and attributes related to that job.

```
    String table_online_id = "";
    String table_reference = "";
    String shorcut_table_online = "";
    String shorcut_table_reference = "";
    String attribute_table_online ="";

    if (tabla_consultar.equalsIgnoreCase(CommandArgument.CUSTOMER.name())) {
        table_online_id = "online_id_customer";
        table_reference = "customer_reference";
        shorcut_table_online = "oidc";
        attribute_table_online = "customer";
        shorcut_table_reference = "cr";
    }else if (tabla_consultar.equalsIgnoreCase(CommandArgument.PRODUCT.name())) {
        table_online_id = "online_id_product";
        table_reference = "product_reference";
        shorcut_table_online = "oidp";
        attribute_table_online = "product";
        shorcut_table_reference = "pr";
    }else {
        table_online_id = "online_id_account";
        table_reference = "account_reference";
        shorcut_table_online = "oida";
        attribute_table_online = "account";
        shorcut_table_reference = "ar";
    }
```

For example:

```
reader.setSql("select ul.user_name  as \"userName\"," + shorcut_table_reference +".urn as \"urn\", ace.wbu_action as \"action\", al.code as \"accreditation_level\", ace.date as \"fecha\"\r\n" 
                    + " from " + table_online_id +" "+ shorcut_table_online +", online_entity_association oea, accreditation_event ace, " + table_reference + " " +  shorcut_table_reference +", user_login ul, acreditation_level al \r\n"
                    + " where " + shorcut_table_online+".id=oea.id and \r\n" + " oea.id=ace.id and \r\n"
                    + " "+shorcut_table_online+"."+attribute_table_online+"=" + shorcut_table_reference +".id and \r\n" + " ul.online_identity="+shorcut_table_online+".online_identity and \r\n" + " ace.level=al.id and \r\n"
                    + " ace.date<'" + date + "'");
```

To finish the variable "tabla_consultar" is used as part of the file name, this way I can be sure that if the query I want to make is from CUSTOMER, the file will be xxxx-Customer-xxxx, varying if I ask from ACCOUNT or PRODUCT, therefore achieving that the file is not overwritten, this could also have been achieved by adding the value of hh:mm:ss.

```
DateFormat hourdateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
        String outputName = outputDir + "wxxxxxxx-"+ tabla_consultar +"-"+ hourdateFormat.format(date) + ".txt";
        File file = new File(outputName);
```